# PHP Group items in a report table

Tags: php

Designing a report that is displayed (PHP outputting HTML) in tables.  Data looks like this (coloring not mine):

```
Date         PID  Client Name  Activity         Hours
2012-10-15   52   Company Y    Report writing   3.5
2012-10-15   16   Company D    Meeting          1.3
2012-10-15   21   Company F    Telecon          0.3
2012-10-15   52   Company Y    Telecon          0.8
2012-10-16   16   Company D    Client visit     1.7
2012-10-16   52   Company Y    Preparation      1.8
2012-10-16   16   Company D    Edit MMS 12      7.1
```

I've written everything to get the data from MySQL, extract it line-by-line (`mysql_fetch_assoc`), construct an HTML table that contains the values, and output. Basic stuff - did it through jQuery calling Ajax, looks great.

I've now been asked to group the items by CID/CompanyName (same thing) and output (I figure as separate tables) with a summary total of hours-per-company below each companytable.

I'd like to use only one mysql_query, so that means doing the groups/calcs in PHP.

I've just worked through a 3-day weekend finishing a db restructure and writing the initial report and I'm having difficulty thinking this through. Would a kind soul help me with the approach? I've started several different algorithms and they spaghetti out of control. I know there's an elegant, simple approach but at the moment I cannot conceive of it.

Comment: Tell us a little about what you've tried. Also, you can totally GROUP BY and summarize within MySQL. :)

Comment: And it might be worth making multiple queries at this point if it makes your life easier. The overhead won't be too bad, and performance is practically NEVER a limiting factor for these types of intranet/reports apps.

Comment: Working on the first. I thought of that, but PID and ClientName are tied together. How would I structure that query? (I've worked myself into one of those blurry-vision situations.)

Comment: There's a pretty good tutorial here: http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlgroupby.php the salient point is that (I suspect) a nice, straightforward `SELECT company, sum(hours) FROM products GROUP BY company` should take care of the hours summaries. Disclaimer, I'm a PostgreSQL dev, and I only use MySQL when necessary - but that should still work!

Comment: Thank you very much, you've given me the starting point I needed. Very grateful for the hand-up.

Comment: Not a problem. I've been post-deadline on a massive SQL project for about a week and a half and I can't alter the database schema or anything. Loads and loads and loads of subqueries (which might be useful to you too - you can totally do stuff like `SELECT chocolate, (SELECT producename FROM produce WHERE producetype=fruit LIMIT 1) AS fruits;` and it'll work, more or less by magic. It's not the best way to do most things but especially with autogenerated DB schemas it can be the only sensible way.

Comment: That's a good suggestion, thank you. All the best for your project - sounds enviably cool.

Comment: I wrote a little class when I had the same issue. It lets me use 1 query and do all kinds of aggregation on the data in php. Maybe it or something similar will work. https://github.com/willoller/PHP-report-helper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With kind direction from user `sudowned`, who put me onto the right track, I was able to finish the project. For future readers, here is what worked for me:

THIS IS ALGORITHM:

```
$rCards = Get all time entries for specific user within certain date range
$rCardsPJ = Get PID (project_num)s between those dates
Top Loop (through all projects)
    $TopLoopPID = get next project_num
    $ttl_hrs_this_pj = 0;

    Loop through all time entries ($rCards)
        get next rCard
        if (PID on this rCard == $TopLoopPID) {
            echo this row
            $hrs_this_rCard = get hrs from this rCard
            $ttl_hrs_this_pj += $hrs_this_rCard
        }
    }
    echo 'Total Hours: ' . $ttl_hrs_this_pj;
}
```

THIS IS CODE:

```
$rCards = mysql_query("SELECT `t_id`, `date`, `project_num`, `task_desc`, `hours` FROM `timecards` WHERE `staff_id`='$staff_id' AND `date` BETWEEN '$date_start' AND '$date_finish'");
$rCardsPJ = mysql_query("SELECT `project_num`, COUNT(`project_num`) FROM `timecards` WHERE `staff_id`='$staff_id' AND `date` BETWEEN '$date_start' AND '$date_finish' GROUP BY `project_num`");

$num_cards = mysql_num_rows($rCards);
$num_projs = mysql_num_rows($rCardsPJ);

//If no time cards for this period, respond with a single zero
if ($num_cards < 1) {
    echo '0';
    exit();
}

$t = ''; //Initialize var (necc)

$cntr = 1;
for($i = 1; $i<=$num_projs; $i++){
//Loop through each project
    $aPJ = mysql_fetch_assoc($rCardsPJ);
    $this_pj = $aPJ['project_num'];
    $this_pjCnt = $aPJ['COUNT(`project_num`)'];
    //Counter for row striping
    $stripe_cnt = 0;

    $csv .= '"Date","PJ#","Project Name","Task Description","Hours"'.chr(13);
    $t .= '<table style="width:90%;background:white;border-radius:10px;margin:-8px 0 3px 0; padding:10px 20px;box-shadow:2px 2px 5px;">
        <tr>
            <th width="90">
                Date
            </th>
            <th width="50">
                PJ #
            </th>
            <th width="250">
                Project Name
            </th>
            <th width="500">
                Description
            </th>
            <th width="50">
                Hours
            </th>
            <th width="10">
                Edit
            </th>
        </tr>
        ';
    $ttl_hrs_this_pj = 0;
    for($j = 1; $j<=$num_cards; $j++){
        $crd = mysql_fetch_assoc($rCards);
            $pj = $crd['project_num'];
            /*---------------------------------------------------------------------*/
            if($pj == $this_pj) {
                $date = $crd['date'];
                $project_num = add_zeros($crd['project_num'], '3');
                $project_name = get_project_name_from_project_num($project_num);
                $task = $crd['task_desc'];
                $hours = $crd['hours'];
                $t_id = $crd['t_id'];
                $ttl_hrs_this_pj += $hours;

                $stripe_cnt++; //for row striping
                $stripe = (is_odd($stripe_cnt)) ? 'class="tr_odd"' : 'class="tr_even"' ;

                $t .= '<tr '.$stripe.'>
                    <td>
                        '.$date.'
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        '.$project_num.'
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        '.$project_name.'
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        '.$task.'
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align:right;">
                        '.$hours.'
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <img id="tc_"'.$t_id.' class="tc_edit" src="images/Edit_Icon.jp">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                ';
            }

    }
                $t .='<tr>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span class="SumHoursLabel">Total Hours:</span>
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align:right;">
                        <span class="SumHoursValue">'.number_format($ttl_hrs_this_pj,2).'</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
                <br />';

                //Reset counter to top for this mysql resource
                mysql_data_seek($rCards,0);

                $cntr++;
}
echo $t;
```